# main() function will not output value for coin_to_bag

Tags: python, dictionary, program-entry-point

**Im getting an error of:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File ".\file.py", line 113, in <module>
    main()
  File ".\file.py", line 111, in main
    cs_in_the_b = assign_c2b(bs, cs, c2b)
NameError: global name 'c2b' is not defined
```

**When I run my code:**

```
cs = ['quarter','dime','nickel']
bs = ['sm','med','lg']

def assign_c2b(bs, cs):
    '''
    assign_c2b() assigns cs to bs
    specifically c2b{} stores this association between the c and b
    '''
    c2b = {}#'test'}
    print('Here are your bs:\n')
    print(bs)
    print('\n')
    print('Here are your c types:\n')
    print (cs)

    for b in bs:
        c_type = input('Number of this type?    e.g. type 1 for Quarter "["Quarter", "Nickel"]" ')  #e.g. 0.25 * 2
        c_amount = input('Number of this type?  e.g. 15')  #e.g. 0.25 * 2
        for c in cs:
            c2b[b] = [c_type, c_amount]

    print(c2b)

    return (c2b)


def main():
    bs = gather_b()
    cs = gather_c()
    cs_in_the_b = assign_c2b(bs, cs, c2b)

main()
```

Im simply trying to get my var `c2b`to display something when called in `main()` . Perhaps I am totally overlooking the reason, but havent been able to figure this out. Can someone help? Thank you!!

Comment: Your `assign_coin_to_bag` function, as defined, only takes 2 arguments, yet you are passing it 3 in `main()`. I suspect you don't actually want the 3rd argument, since the function seems to construct your dictionary.

Comment: Only `bs` and `cs` are defined in `main`, where is `c2b` supposed to come from in the `assign_c2b` call?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def main():
    bags = gather_bag()
    coins = gather_coin()
    coins_in_the_bag = assign_coin_to_bag(bags, coins, coin_to_bag)
```

`coin_to_bag` is never defined when calling `assign_coin_to_bag`.

Even if it was defined, `assign_coin_to_bag` expects 2 arguments (`def assign_coin_to_bag(bags, coins)` but you are trying to call it with 3.

Comment: Wow, this really helps. I think i've been looking at this too long. Thanks again @DeepSpace